# Remove Ads From Categories

Tags: wordpress, ads

How To Remove Ads From Individual Categories - (using worpdress)
I want to make sure that all posts filed in that category don’t display any ads.

Comment: What do you use to display the ads? A plugin? Is the ad code included in the theme?

Comment: the ad code included in the theme

Comment: Why dnt you try to remove the code of ads in theme pages.

Comment: Not a problem, but i want to remove only from specific category (e.g Auto)

Comment: Modify the view file and insert a conditional to only display if category !="auto" or whichever

Comment: This Plugin helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your archive.php file (or whatever is the file where the ad code is located)

```
$category = get_the_category();
$category = $categories[0]->slug;
if($category != 'whatever-is-the-slug')
{
  // code to display your ads goes here
  echo 'Look, these are my ads :-)';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a plugin for this. Of course you can define this manually, but if you decide in some month to change your ad setup or you change the policy of your category ads, you will have to do a lot of extra work. 
With flexible and free ad managers like Advanced Ads (https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-ads) you have the full control about your ads and where they appear/hide.

Comment: This Plugin helped me. Thank you to everyone